# How do I get equations to line up not around the equals sign?

Tags: equations

Currently my input

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote} 
\usepackage{accents}  
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\underaccent{\tilde}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*} 
v\frac{dv}{dx} & = -k(v+v^3)\\
 -\int_u^v\frac{1}{1+v^2} dv & = \int_0^x k\; dx \\
 \left[\tan^{-1}(v)\right]^u_v & =\left[kx\right]^x_0\\
 \tan^{-1}(u)-\tan^{-1}(v) & = kx \\
  v & = \tan\left(\tan^{-1}(u)-kx\right) \\
\end{align*}


\end{document}
```

produces the following.

[image]

I was wondering if anyone could help line up the equations so that each line after the next is generally centred, like how it would look like if you wrote working out on paper rather than just having all the equals signs lining up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best idea [by @daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646828/how-do-i-get-equations-to-line-up-not-around-the-equals-sign/646831#comment1611718_646831): use a `gather*` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{gather*}
    v\frac{dv}{dx} = -k(v+v^3)\\
     -\int_u^v\frac{1}{1+v^2} dv = \int_0^x k\; dx \\
     \left[\tan^{-1}(v)\right]^u_v =\left[kx\right]^x_0\\
     \tan^{-1}(u)-\tan^{-1}(v) = kx \\
      v = \tan\left(\tan^{-1}(u)-kx\right)
  \end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My first idea was the following, but with it, the integral signs are not in `\displaystyle`: you can use a `\begin{array}{c}` and adjust the spacing between rows via array.sty's `\extrarowheight` parameter. `\jot` is the amount of extra vertical spacing that `\halign`-based environments insert between rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
   \setlength{\extrarowheight}{\jot}
   \begin{array}{c}
     v\frac{dv}{dx} = -k(v+v^3)\\
      -\int_u^v\frac{1}{1+v^2} dv = \int_0^x k\; dx \\
      \left[\tan^{-1}(v)\right]^u_v =\left[kx\right]^x_0\\
      \tan^{-1}(u)-\tan^{-1}(v) = kx \\
       v = \tan\left(\tan^{-1}(u)-kx\right)
   \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

It is possible to add `\displaystyle` to each row using `\begin{array}{>{\displaystyle} c }` but still, `gather*` gives better row spacing around the tall integral signs. The result with `\begin{array}{>{\displaystyle} c }` would be as follows:

[image]

Comment: Why an array here and not just gather*? Then the integrals will have the proper size as well

Comment: Because I didn't think about it! I let you write your answer or can incorporate this, as you prefer.

Comment: Just rewrite yours (I'm on a tablet takes too long to type a answer )

Comment: Done, thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

In Plain TeX, we have `\displaylines` macro:

```
$$\displaylines{
   v{dv\over dx} = -k(v+v^3) \cr
   -\int_u^v{1\over 1+v^2} dv = \int_0^x k\; dx \cr
   \left[\tan^{-1}(v)\right]^u_v = [kx]^x_0 \cr
   \tan^{-1}(u)-\tan^{-1}(v) = kx \cr
   v = \tan\left(\tan^{-1}(u)-kx\right)
}$$

\bye
```