# Remove horizontal indentation from an array

Tags: amsmath, arrays

How can I remove horizontal indentation from an array ***globally***?

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\section{Test 1 -- normal}
$f(x) =\sin(x)+\cos(x)$

$\begin{array}{ l }
f(x) =\sin(x)+\cos(x) \\
g(x) =\sin(x)+\tan(x) \\
\end{array}$


\section{Test 2 -- with noindent}
\noindent$f(x) =\sin(x)+\cos(x)$

\noindent$\begin{array}{ l }
f(x) =\sin(x)+\cos(x) \\
g(x) =\sin(x)+\tan(x) \\
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure what you want, but the “indentation” of formulas 2 and 3 in your second test is due to `\arraycolsep`. It is not inserted if you do `\begin{array}{ @{} l }`. Otherwise, `\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}` removes such indents on the left and right of arrays, and applies to the current TeX group.

Comment: Use `@{} l` instead of `l`. Btw why array here and not a proper displayed math env

Comment: Why not simply  use the `aligned` environment?

Comment: @cis You can look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/646831/73317) to understand why @daleif suggests not to use `array` here. ;-)

Comment: the indent is unrelated to the array, it is paragraph indent already added when you started the paragraph. Don't use a paragraph with inline math, use a display math environment, (and `array` is for matrices of values, not aligned equations)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There are several “indentations” at play here. In the `Test 2` section, it is definitely `\arraycolsep` which (visually) “indents” lines 2 and 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For fully automatic flush-left (aka fully right-aligned) placement of the `array` environments, you need to set two length parameters -- `\parindent` and `\arraycolsep` -- to `0pt`. Be sure to delimit the scope of these resets, e.g., via `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` directives.

A separate remark: It's not really a good idea to employ a single-column `array` environment to display rows of equations. For that purpose, it's much better to use one of the multi-row display math environments of the `amsmath` package. In "section 4" below, I therefore employ an `aligned` environment, which allows alignment on the `=` symbols. Observe also the increased spacing among the rows of the `aligned` environment when compared with the spacing of the `array` environments.

The frameline along the left-hand edge of the following screenshot shows up because the `geometry` package is loaded with the option `showframe`.

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\begin{document}

\section{Without either \texttt{\string\noindent} or \texttt{@\{\}}}
$\cdots$

$\begin{array}{l}
f(x) =\sin(x)+\cos(x) \\
g(x) =\sin(x)+\tan(x) 
\end{array}$


\section{With \texttt{\string\noindent} but without \texttt{@\{\}}}

$\cdots$

\noindent
$\begin{array}{l}
f(x) =\sin(x)+\cos(x) \\
g(x) =\sin(x)+\tan(x) 
\end{array}$


\section{With both \texttt{\string\noindent} and \texttt{@\{\}}}

$\cdots$

\noindent
$\begin{array}{@{}l}
f(x) =\sin(x)+\cos(x) \\
g(x) =\sin(x)+\tan(x) 
\end{array}$

\section{Automatic treatment, alignment on = symbols}

$\cdots$

\begingroup  % limit the scope of the next two directives

\setlength\parindent{0pt}   
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}

$\begin{aligned}
f(x) &=\sin(x)+\cos(x) \\
g(x) &=\sin(x)+\tan(x) 
\end{aligned}$

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: this is technically, true, but I think misses the real answer which is "don't use `array` for displayed equations" (ie use (4))

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks. I've gone ahead and added a paragraph to state explicitly that one shouldn't use a single-column `array` environment to display multiple-row groups of equations.

Comment: +1 then:-).....